# Gridview rowdatabound error : Multiple controls with the same ID 'hlLink' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has link and description to be rendered on the page.

written the below code in gridview in .aspx

```
      <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <p>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlLink" runat="server" Target="_self"></asp:HyperLink></p>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <p>
                    <asp:Literal ID="litSummary" runat="server"></asp:Literal></p>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <p>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlLink" runat="server" Target="_self"></asp:HyperLink></p>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <p>
                    <asp:Literal ID="litSummary" runat="server"></asp:Literal></p>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

and below in .aspx.csin gridview rowdataboundevent

```
    protected void gvResults_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            SearchResultItem data = (SearchResultItem)e.Row.DataItem;
            HyperLink hlLink = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hlLink");
            Literal litSummary = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("litSummary");
            if (data.Description != null)
            {
                hlLink.Text = data.Title;
                hlLink.NavigateUrl = data.Path.Replace("&amp;", "&");
                litSummary.Text = data.Description;
            }
            else
            {
                hlLink.Text = data.Path;
                hlLink.NavigateUrl = data.Path.Replace("&amp;", "&");
                litSummary.Text = data.Path;
            }

        }
```

here SearchResultItem: is the result item that has link and description details.
First time when row bound event is called, it binds the data correctly, second time when called throws error "Multiple controls with the same ID 'hlLink' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Please let me know whats error with the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** you are trying to create the same controls with same ID multiple times.

**Solution :**  you need to remove the controls before creating them.

Try This:

```
void RemoveControls()
    {
    HyperLink l1 = (HyperLink)Page.FindControl("hlLink"); 
    Literal l2 = (Literal)Page.FindControl("litSummary"); 


    if(l1!= null)
        Page.Controls.Remove(l1);

    if(l2!= null)
        Page.Controls.Remove(l2);        
    }
```

**Solution 2:** Pagination for Repeater control.
for implementing `pagination` in `Repeater` control you need to create `PagedDataSource`.

Try This:

```
PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
pds.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView; 
pds.AllowPaging = true;
pds.PageSize = 8;//page sizes
```

Comment: Hi Sudhakar,instead of using gridview i used repeater control to solve the issue. Thanks for the post. Now I'm stuck with implemeting custom pagination of repeater to display in numeric format i.e. 1 2 3 4 5 6  if you kno how to od it, could you please let me know

Comment: @user166013: good, you can see my edited answer with section `solution2`